# Optimising this small function which will run a huge number of times in C

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, optimization

Here is the worst case scenario for each part of the function:

- The `while` loop runs 53,402 times when `size` is equal to 9.
- This means that each call of `find_square()` calls `find_square()` itself 53,402 times, until `row == size`, which in this case is 9.

So the total number of calls to `find_square()` is thus (53,402) ^ 10 = 
188 quattuordecillion.

This isn't even the entirety of the final function, but if it's this slow already, I'm wanting to fix that first. Obviously this is a ludicrous amount of calls, but I can't really see a way around it. I'm open to any ideas, and any help here would be great, thank you!

```
void find_square(char*** hashed_dict, char*** grouped_dict, char** square, int size, int row) {

    if (row == size) {
        return;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (grouped_dict[size - 1][i] != NULL) {
        fill_row(square, row, size, grouped_dict[size - 1][i]);
        find_square(hashed_dict, grouped_dict, square, size, row + 1);
        i++;
    }
}

void fill_row(char** square, int row, int size, char* word) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        square[row][i] = word[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not enough context. And speaking about performance and manual optimizations without a specific system in mind is not really meaningful.

Comment: What context do you want?

Comment: Have you considered a "dynamic programming" approach?

Comment: What is the container, some sort of hash table? How is it implemented? Why do you use three star programming instead of ADT? Where are the struct definitions? _What system do you optimize for_? Which compiler? Etc etc.

Comment: `grouped_dict` is essentially an array of strings. The application aims to create all possible 'word squares' which are squares of letters such that each row and each column form valid words. There are no structs. I'm operating on a Macbook Pro using XCode.

Comment: I don't think we need to worry too much about the compiler until we can reduce 1e47 to something manageable ;)  That said, it's not clear what the goal of this code is - what problem is it solving?

Comment: @numberjak: ADT is Abstract Data Type btw.

Comment: How do you compile this code?

Comment: Please provide a brief (preferably one sentence) description of what that function is supposed to do. "find square" can mean a lot of things. I shouldn't have to single-step the code in my head just to figure out what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: If your algorithm is going to require `(53,402) ^ 10` recursive calls, you need a better algorithm, not faster code.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment about creating “word squares” implies you want to print or otherwise report 9⨉9 squares in which each row and column is a word in `grouped_dict`. In this case, you ought to at least return from `find_square` when the characters filled so far contain a partial row or column that is impossible to complete with a word.

One approach is to add code in `find_square` after the call to `fill_row` that checks the columns. After `fill_row`, each column is at least partially filled. For each column, check that there is at least one word in `grouped_dict` that matches the column so far. If there is not, return from `find_square` without attempting to fill any more.

This will speed up your program tremendously, but other optimizations may be possible. Things you should consider include:

- Sort `grouped_dict` so that search for matches in it is fast.
- Index `grouped_dict` in sophisticated ways to search for matches even faster.
- Alternately filling rows and columns to attempt to increase conflicts that may reveal impossible-to-complete states sooner.
- Use the partial matches found by examining `grouped_dict` to limit the possibilities attempted when filling the next row or column.
- Focus on infrequent letters in `grouped_dict` as key points.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the code *does* have an observable effect; it modifies the values in the `square` array.

Comment: @JimMischel: Thanks, I missed that. I have edited.